# Boost Python - debugging python code embedded in C++

Tags: python, c++, boost

I am using boost::python to embed python interpreter to my executable. I call python functions from C++ side. However, I cannot debug python side of the code. It seems that this is not a popular issue but I really need to debug the python code called from C++. It seems that visual studio has a support for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-mixed-mode-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) but I am using ubuntu. Is there a way that I can achieve debugging python code called from C++. I can use another library if boost::python does not support that.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a native debugger called [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Use the lines:

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

to start an interactive debugging session at any point in your python code.